# Parse from array in api using encodable-decodable

Tags: ios, json, swift

I have an api response snippet that looks like so...

```
{
  "status": "OK",
  "predictions": [
    {
      "description": "Hilton Head Island, SC, USA",
      "id": "67bd386c0fb3d4f77bf3cb283a6d75565ea11732",
      "matched_substrings": [
        {
          "length": 6,
          "offset": 0
        }
      ],
      "place_id": "ChIJrRnTjtx5_IgRPSii63qm5Sw",
      "reference": "ChIJrRnTjtx5_IgRPSii63qm5Sw",
      "structured_formatting": {
        "main_text": "Hilton Head Island",
        "main_text_matched_substrings": [
          {
            "length": 6,
            "offset": 0
          }
        ],
        "secondary_text": "SC, USA"
      },
      "types": [
        "locality",
        "political",
        "geocode"
      ]
    }
}
```

From this I want the `main_text` and `secondary_text`. For that I made a model class like so...

```
class FilteredLocations: Codable {

  var locationDetails: [String: Any]

  enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case locationDetails = "structured_formatting"
  }

  required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    locationDetails = try? values.decode([String: Any].self, forKey: .locationDetails)//ERROR HERE
  }

  func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
    var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    try container.encode(locationDetails, forKey: .locationDetails)//ERROR HERE
  }
}
```

But in the above code, at the place mentioned `//ERROR HERE` it throws the error `Reference to member 'locationDetails' cannot be resolved without a contextual type`

What have I done wrong...?

**EDIT 1** : This is how I'm parsing the data..

```
 if let productService = result?["predictions"] as? [[String: Any]] ,
          let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: productService as Any, options: []) {
          do {
            let filteredLocations = try? JSONDecoder().decode(FilteredLocations.self, from: jsonData)

            self.tableview.reloadData()
          } catch {
            print("error \(error.localizedDescription)")
          }
        }
```

**EDIT 2** The google api response:

```
{
   "predictions" : [
      {
         "description" : "Hilton Head Island, SC, USA",
         "id" : "gfhgj3hgjhsgvh4hj4hgj424hfjhjha11732",
         "matched_substrings" : [
            {
               "length" : 6,
               "offset" : 0
            }
         ],
         "place_id" : "dfgegregergrgrergergewrer5Sw",
         "reference" : "bvEQfdgetehetheterbgcbng5Sw",
         "structured_formatting" : {
            "main_text" : "Hilton Head Island",
            "main_text_matched_substrings" : [
               {
                  "length" : 6,
                  "offset" : 0
               }
            ],
            "secondary_text" : "SC, USA"
         },
         "terms" : [
            {
               "offset" : 0,
               "value" : "Hilton Head Island"
            },
            {
               "offset" : 20,
               "value" : "SC"
            },
            {
               "offset" : 24,
               "value" : "USA"
            }
         ],
         "types" : [ "locality", "political", "geocode" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

**EDIT 3** How I make the api call and fetch data to parse..

```
WebServiceClient.shared.getNearbyLocationsSearchList(withParameters: parameters, inputText: searchText) { [weak self] (isSuccess, result) in
  guard let `self` = self else { return }
  if isSuccess, result != nil {
    print("Successfully fetched nearby locations!")

    if let productService = result?["predictions"] as? [[String: Any]] ,
      let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: productService as Any, options: []) {
      do {
        let filteredLocations = try? JSONDecoder().decode([FilteredLocations].self, from: jsonData)

      } catch {
        print("error \(error.localizedDescription)")
      }
    }        
  }
```

**EDIT 4** This is the `result` from api after calling the webservice..

```
{
    description = "Houston, TX, USA";
    id = 25faf0a7ef1056b980f3a19237cfa8e295668123;
    "matched_substrings" =     (
                {
            length = 1;
            offset = 0;
        }
    );
    "place_id" = ChIJAYWNSLS4QIYROwVl894CDco;
    reference = ChIJAYWNSLS4QIYROwVl894CDco;
    "structured_formatting" =     {
        "main_text" = Houston;
        "main_text_matched_substrings" =         (
                        {
                length = 1;
                offset = 0;
            }
        );
        "secondary_text" = "TX, USA";
    };
    terms =     (
                {
            offset = 0;
            value = Houston;
        },
                {
            offset = 9;
            value = TX;
        },
                {
            offset = 13;
            value = USA;
        }
    );
    types =     (
        locality,
        political,
        geocode
    );
}
```

**EDIT 5**

[image]

Comment: Use this http://www.jsoncafe.com/ to create json model.

Comment: I deleted my answer because I was assuming that the response is a JSON string rather than a dictionary..

Comment: That's ok @vadian...:) But would you mind suggesting an answer for this current problem..?

Comment: As you have already a dictionary I'd parse it the traditional way with key and index subscription. And **never ever** `try?` while developing code. `Catch`, read and fix the errors! Decoding errors are very descriptive.

Comment: Now with all that's been tried...things seem confusing @vadian...I have a model class like u suggested in your post at first and when I decode the result that I get(the result is also not nil), I get nil. To be specific, nil here at `filteredLocations` `let filteredLocations = try? JSONDecoder().decode([FilteredLocations].self, from: jsonData)`

Comment: For the last time **catch the error**. Remove the question mark after `try` and `print(error)` **not** `print(error.localizedDescription)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are referring to this JSON, (which is valid, not like the one you attached...)

```
{
    "status": "OK",
    "predictions": [{
        "description": "Hilton Head Island, SC, USA",
        "id": "67bd386c0fb3d4f77bf3cb283a6d75565ea11732",
        "matched_substrings": [{
            "length": 6,
            "offset": 0
        }],
        "place_id": "ChIJrRnTjtx5_IgRPSii63qm5Sw",
        "reference": "ChIJrRnTjtx5_IgRPSii63qm5Sw",
        "structured_formatting": {
            "main_text": "Hilton Head Island",
            "main_text_matched_substrings": [{
                "length": 6,
                "offset": 0
            }],
            "secondary_text": "SC, USA"
        },
        "types": [
            "locality",
            "political",
            "geocode"
        ]
    }]
}
```

Then this is how to create the structure for ALL of the JSON data:

```
struct FilteredLocations: Codable {
    let status: String
    let predictions: [Prediction]
}

struct Prediction: Codable {
    let description, id: String
    let matchedSubstrings: [MatchedSubstring]
    let placeID, reference: String
    let structuredFormatting: StructuredFormatting
    let types: [String]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case description, id
        case matchedSubstrings = "matched_substrings"
        case placeID = "place_id"
        case reference
        case structuredFormatting = "structured_formatting"
        case types
    }
}

struct MatchedSubstring: Codable {
    let length, offset: Int
}

struct StructuredFormatting: Codable {
    let mainText: String
    let mainTextMatchedSubstrings: [MatchedSubstring]
    let secondaryText: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case mainText = "main_text"
        case mainTextMatchedSubstrings = "main_text_matched_substrings"
        case secondaryText = "secondary_text"
    }
}
```

And then decode like so:

```
let filteredLocations = try? JSONDecoder().decode(FilteredLocations.self, from: jsonData)
```

To encode data:

```
let encoder = JSONEncoder()
encoder.outputFormatting = .prettyPrinted

do {
    let jsonData = try encoder.encode(filteredLocations)

    if let jsonString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8) {
        print(jsonString)
        // Prints out the JSON you just encoded.
    }
} catch {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

To get the main and secondary text:

```
main: filteredLocations.structuredFormatting.mainText
secondary: filteredLocations.structuredFormatting.secondaryText
```

I hope this answer has been useful!

**EDIT 1:**

Try this code:

```
WebServiceClient.shared.getNearbyLocationsSearchList(withParameters: parameters, inputText: searchText) { [weak self] (isSuccess, result) in
  guard let `self` = self else { return }
  if isSuccess, result != nil {
    print("Successfully fetched nearby locations!")

    if let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: result as Any, options: []) {
      do {
        let filteredLocations = try? JSONDecoder().decode([FilteredLocations].self, from: jsonData)

      } catch {
        print("error \(error.localizedDescription)")
      }
    }        
  }
```